# Is null condition checking in a select query

Tags: mysql

Tablename : Employee

select name,age,photopath from employee;

I need to re frame the query, ie if the photo path is null, then i need to return photo cloumn which is a BLOB.

photopath - will be http://www.servername.com/imagename.html

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the Blob is null when there is a path, why not just return both columns and put the logic in the code. If you return different datatypes in the same column the app is going to have to figure out which one it got, which is more of a headache.

Comment: @JohnFX - Am checking for file path, if that's null, am loading the Blob image.

Comment: Okay, since you are checking in your code anyway. Why not return both columns from your query? Problem solved.

Comment: No the objective is to remove BLOB column, hence this workaround.

Comment: Remove the BLOB column from the query? Why are you so keen on that, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to check for the condition, and return one of two columns. Possibly in combination with `AS` to create an unique field name (if that is your goal).

Comment: I need to use only select query, not stored procedure.

Comment: @Sharpeye `IF()` has nothing to do with stored procedures. You mean `IF` (without `()`)

Comment: select if(isnull(photopath), photo) from employees; I don't get it right. Please correct me.

Comment: @Sharpeye `select if(isnull(photopath), photo, photopath) AS photo` should do the job. However, @JohnFx has a point too.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT IF(field1 IS NULL, field2, field1) FROM table1;